# Changing the Login block HTML for D7

Tags: 7, users

I want to change the form elements a bit in the login block for D7 to add the following to the input elements:

```
onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Username'" onfocus="if(this.value =='Username' ) this.value=''"
```

I would prefer not to create a new module just for this via hook form alter, and I did not see a user block to override in the User module.

Is there a template.php function that could be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to do access the form elements directly like that. You can use some unobtrusive JavaScript with jQuery to do the same thing.

```
;(function ($){
    Drupal.behaviors.YOUR_FUNCTION = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {
                    // your script goes here...
               };   
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Create a scripts file and add the above. Add a reference to that file in your .info file.

Then add your script.

Some references if your not familiar with jQuery.

- http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/blur/
- http://api.jquery.com/focus/
- http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: ah, great approach. I thought about that, but then thought what if they have javascript turned off? I soon realized the error of my logic. thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help ;-)